# D365 OnPrem - Wipe out default business units migrated from dev to test

Tags: dynamics-crm

I used the migration utility to migrate schema and data from my dev environment to my test environment. In doing so, the default dev business units were migrated to test. How do I wipe that business unit that got migrated?

I’ve wiped out every dependency I can think of.  Only problem is that the dev default team got migrated as well. Can't change that to correct business unit and can't delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You can rename that BU & team to match your expectation. We need to keep the BU & Team records guid in sync across environments. That’s why we are migrating the data using utility, otherwise we can create them manually & create confusions/issues like WF not activating after solution import during deployment.

For example if your Dev BU & team has some naming convention different than Test instance - then you may rename it.